# NullPointerException trying set two models zk

Tags: zk

When I set single model in my controller (zk) all is good, but when I try do this for more than one model, I have the error `java.lang.NullPointerException`. What is my error?
Here the code...

```java
public void doAfterCompose (Component comp) throws Exception {
    super.doAfterCompose(comp);

    // set models and render to listbox after composed
    articuloListBox.setModel(getArticulosModel());
    articuloListBox.setItemRenderer(new ArticulosRenderer());

    // Setting this second model the error is trow....
    try {
        familiaListBox.setModel(getFamiliasModel());
        familiaListBox.setItemRenderer(new FamiliasRenderer());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: "+e);
    }
}
```

Here is the full stacktrace...

> Grave:   java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   controllers.ArticulosViewController.doAfterCompose(ArticulosViewController.java:89)
>     at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.doAfterCompose(UiEngineImpl.java:529)
>     at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:824)
>     at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:770)
>     at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:679)
>     at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:643)
>     at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:394)
>     at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:316)
>     at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:215)
>     at
>   org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:135)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Can you post the **full** exception stacktrace?. It seems that `familiaListBox` is null.

Comment: I do not know which line number is 89 but i am sure issue with getArticulosModel() or getFamiliasModel()() better share more code so i can help you

Comment: Post the part where you set/get familiaListBox and the zul for it. The error shuld come fomr there.